# How do you render an aspx in a master page in asp net webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do you switch between two different pieces of code in the master page, that both contain header, body and footer tags, like a regular aspx page? I have the option to add a condition at the top of the masterpage:

```
<% if(condition) { %> 
Code1 
<% } else { %> 
Code2 
<% } %>
```

Would it be best to isolate Code1 and Code2 in separate files (aspx?) and how would I render them in this case?
PS I would rather not put the code in ascx because the difference in structure between the two pieces of codes, i would rather replace the code in its entirety

Comment: why don't you use single aspx page with above conditions? are you getting any errors with it?

Comment: Use the code behind, it's not classic asp. Use the code behind and if you want conditioned code then put it in a literal control and hide or show the literal from the code behind.

Comment: From the sound of your question, I'd go with the loading of different user control (ascx) approach; despite your unwillingness.